# Setting Y Axis values on matplotlib chart, incrementing

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, charts

Please may someone assist me on this. I am trying to add Y Axis values to my matplotlib chart so the chart looks like this Excel Chart:

[image]

However, on my matplotlib chart, the Y Axis values are from 0-6:

[image]

Is there some code I have left out here to add the values to the chart? Do I need to manually specify the values for them to be in increments of £10 million? I'm still very new to this sorry!

```
df_total_gross_sales.set_index('Date').plot.bar()

plt.title('Gross Sales: Discounted Vs Full Price', pad = 10, Fontsize =16)
plt.ylabel("Gross Sales (£)", labelpad = 10, fontsize=14)
plt.xlabel("Year-Month", labelpad = 20, fontsize=14)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.legend(facecolor='white', fontsize =13,  framealpha=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add

```py
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter('₤{x:,}')
```

Somewhere before `show`.

A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.arange(30)
y=np.random.randint(5000000, 70000000, (30,))
plt.bar(x,y)
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter('₤{x:,}')
plt.show()
```

Gives
[image]

The same example, without that line, shows a y-axis with ticks labelled from 0 to 7, with, as in your example, in legend saying that those are ×10⁷ units.

Note that the ticks value in this format string is always named `x` (even tho it is y axis).

Comment: Thanks for the help chrslg. I really appreciate this. Working well now :)

Comment: Is there any way to remove the trailing decimal on the Y values? Thanks

Comment: @Conor Yes. Use `'₤{x:,.0f}'` instead of `£{x:,}` for format string. Those are the same as [f-string](https://pyneng.readthedocs.io/en/latest/book/08_python_basic_examples/f-string.html). So you can do whatever you would do with a f-string, `x` being f float value. `x=1234567.0; print(f"£{x:,}")` prints `£1,234,567.0`. `print(f"₤{x:,.0f}")` (meaning "x as float (f) with 0 decimals (.0) and group separator (,)") prints `₤1,234,567`

Comment: Thanks again! Had to read through that a few times but yes I understand now.